# Difference between Shuffle and Random_State in train test split?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried both on a small dataset sample and it returned the same output. So the question is, what is the difference between the "shuffle" and the "random_state" parameter in scikit's train-test-split method?

Code for MWE:

```
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)

Out: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]

train_test_split(y, random_state=0)

Out: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: ```random_state``` will set a seed for reproducibility of the results, whereas ```shuffle``` sets whether the train and tests sets are made of from a shuffled array or not (if set to False, all the n first observations in your array will go in the train dataset, and all others in the test dataset).

Comment: but pratically I can not see a difference if I am setting it to false or choose a fixed random_state. Actually only the order of the original array is preserved when `shuffle=False`, otherwise there would be an initial random reordering which can be kept by setting `random_state=0`.

Comment: I added an answer for clarifications.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sometimes experimenting may help understand how a function works.

Say if you have a DataFrame of the sort:

```
   X  Y
0  A  2
1  A  3
2  A  2
3  B  0
4  B  0
```

We'll go over the different things that you can do with the function `train_test_split`:

---

- if you input `train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=2/5, shuffle=False, random_state=None)`, you will always end up with:

```
# TRAIN
   X  Y
0  A  2
1  A  3
2  A  2

#TEST
   X  Y
3  B  0
4  B  0
```

---

- if you input `train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=2/5, shuffle=False, random_state=1)` or any other int for `random_state`, you will get the same:

```
# TRAIN
   X  Y
0  A  2
1  A  3
2  A  2

#TEST
   X  Y
3  B  0
4  B  0
```

> This comes from the fact that **you decided not to shuffle your dataset**, so `random_state` is not used by the function.

---

- Now, if you do `train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=2/5, shuffle=True, random_state=None)`, you will get a dataset that looks like this:

```
# TRAIN
   X  Y
4  B  0
0  A  2
1  A  3

# TEST
   X  Y
2  A  2
3  B  0
```

> Note that **entries have been shuffled**. But note as well that **if you run your code again, results might differ**.

---

- Finally, if you do `train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=2/5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)` or any other int for `random_state`, you will get two datasets with shuffled entries as well:

```
# TRAIN
   X  Y
4  B  0
0  A  2
3  B  0

# TEST
   X  Y
2  A  2
1  A  3
```

> Only, this time, **if you run the code again with the same** `random_state`, **the output will always remain the same**. You have set a seed, which is useful for reproducibility of the results!

Answer (score 3):

- `random_state` controls the pseudo-random numpy generator. For the reproducibility of the code, a random_state should be specified.
- `shuffle`: if True then it shuffles the data before splitting

More details:

> random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional
>   (default=None) If int, random_state is the seed used by the random
>   number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random
>   number generator; If None, the random number generator is the
>   RandomState instance used by np.random.
>
> shuffle : boolean, optional (default=True) Whether or not to shuffle
>   the data before splitting. If shuffle=False then stratify must be
>   None.